# How to link a variable of a material to another material?

Tags: materials

Let's say I have two materials "material1" and "material2".
How do I achieve that material1's roughness(or anything else) is the same as material2's and changing material2's roughness will change both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this - is using node-groups. This is instruction:

1. Add a node with your parameter for roughness it will be `Value` node:

[image]

2. Select your node than press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. It will create a node group with output from **value** node:

[image]

3. To exit from node-group press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and connect node group to 
   roughness socket.

[image]

4. In <kbd>N</kbd>-pannel you can change name to any that you like:

[image]

5. And finally, in outer material nodes you can add same node-group from `Add`(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)->`Group` menu.

[image]

6. New node will have number near node-group name. It indicates how many copies of this node-group you use.

[image]